# How do I use Power Shell to copy folders from local to remote Linux Server

Tags: powershell, robocopy, powershell-v4.0

I am trying to make a script that will let me update the files on the server by copying then from local. I made a bash script for this task that works on Linux, but a Power Shell script is also needed as my machine at work is running Windows 8.1.

The bash script relies on rsync as follows:

```
rsync -auv \
    -e "ssh -i super-secure.pem -p 2222" \
    --progress project/$folder/ \
    username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:/some/place/on/server/project/$folder
```

I think I have to use `robocopy` but I couldn't understand the proper way to use it and how the .pem and port would be passed. Can anyone please point me on the right direction? Please?

Comment: I suggest to change tool. SyncThing is very good for synchronization of directories, and has ports on various platforms.

Comment: [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com)? Then you can use `rsync` (and possibly your bash script, for that matter) on both ends. I regularly use Cygwin, including `rsync`, on my Win machines and am a big fan.